# User Profile Service site host giving ASP.Net error

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, user-profile, user-profile-service, asp.net

I'm trying to get my sites working on my demo environment but I keep getting this error

[image]

I don't know what to do from here. The error message here is pretty useless.

I did the whole sp_farm account delegation. I have two web applications, one for intranet sites and one for the my sites hosts. I've set up the UPS application and the sync is working without issue. I've enabled Self site creation, added the users to the permissions for the web app, set up the managed path etc etc.

I get this error in my server events:

```
Event code: 3005 
Event message: An unhandled exception has occurred. 
Event time: 2014-04-01 3:39:14 PM 
Event time (UTC): 2014-04-01 7:39:14 PM 
Event ID: 5eaf7a55cb1b4486a480df1532af6bfe 
Event sequence: 18 
Event occurrence: 4 
Event detail code: 0 

Application information: 
    Application domain: /LM/W3SVC/774332291/ROOT-1-130408537553370958 
    Trust level: Full 
    Application Virtual Path: / 
    Application Path: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\mysites.kcorp.com80\ 
    Machine name: SP2013-WFE1 

Process information: 
    Process ID: 10748 
    Process name: w3wp.exe 
    Account name: CONTOSO\sp_admin 

Exception information: 
    Exception type: InvalidOperationException 
    Exception message: Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.SPControl.EnsureSPWebRequest(SPWeb web)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.SPControl.SPWebEnsureSPControl(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.UnsecuredLayoutsPageBase.OnPreInit(EventArgs e)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.LayoutsPageBase.OnPreInit(EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.PerformPreInit()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)



Request information: 
    Request URL: http://mysites.kcorp.com/_layouts/15/MySite.aspx?MySiteRedirect=AllSites 
    Request path: /_layouts/15/MySite.aspx 
    User host address: 10.10.10.3 
    User:  
    Is authenticated: False 
    Authentication Type:  
    Thread account name: CONTOSO\sp_admin 

Thread information: 
    Thread ID: 57 
    Thread account name: CONTOSO\sp_admin 
    Is impersonating: False 
    Stack trace:    at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.SPControl.EnsureSPWebRequest(SPWeb web)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.SPControl.SPWebEnsureSPControl(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.UnsecuredLayoutsPageBase.OnPreInit(EventArgs e)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.LayoutsPageBase.OnPreInit(EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.PerformPreInit()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)


Custom event details:
```

I have this error in my logs:

```
User Profile Application: SynchronizeMIIS encounters an exception: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.    
 at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileImportJob.<>c__DisplayClass2.<IsTimerJobRunning>b__1()    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.<>c__DisplayClass5.<RunWithElevatedPrivileges>b__3()    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SecurityContext.RunAsProcess(CodeToRunElevated secureCode)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(WaitCallback secureCode, Object param)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(CodeToRunElevated secureCode)    
 at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileImportJob.IsTimerJobRunning(UserProfileApplicationJob timerJob)    
 at Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplication.SynchronizeMIIS()    
 at Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.ILMProfileSynchronizationJob.Execute()
```

Not really sure what to do now.

I changed the web config so I could get a more detailed error message:

[image]

Comment: the above error telling me something wrong with UPA, Check couple of things...Make sure UPA & Sync Service is running? try to reboot the server on which UPA sync services running?

Comment: Both services are running and I've rebooted the WFE a few times. Unfortunately that didn't help.

Comment: I am not asking WFE reboot, rather the server which is running the UPA Sync services.

Comment: Oh, I thought if I rebooted the WFE all services rebooted as well?

Comment: If it is a single WFE, then yes. You can put the User Profile Service Application on a different server/s, though.

Comment: I have 3 VM's one for AD, SQL and WFE with all my service. Anyways, I wasn't sure how to restart the service so I just stopped it and started again.